How to solve the probability problem?
Let $X$ be a $ N \times N $ random matrix with i.i.d. random entries, and
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{11} = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X_{11} = -1) = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
Define
$$
\|X\|_{\text{op}} = \sup_{\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{C}^N: \|\mathbf{v}\|_2 = 1} \|X\mathbf{v}\|_2.
$$
Show that for any fixed $\delta > 0 $,
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(\|X\|_{\text{op}} \geq N^{1/2 + \delta}) = 0.
$$
Hint: $\|X\|_{\text{op}}^2 \leq \text{tr}|X|^2.$
My attempt:
I think I should use the fact as follows:
(i)for the maximum singular values :$\sigma_{max}(A)= \max_{\|x\|_{2}=1} {\|Ax\|_{2}}$;
the operator norm of  a matrix:$\|A\|_{\text{op}} = \sigma_{max}(A)$;
For $Q \in S^{d\times d}$ there is a simple relationship between eigenvalues and singular values: $$\{|\lambda(Q)|\}_{k \in[d]}=\{\sigma(Q)\}_{k \in[d]}$$
(ii)(Matrix chernoff).For any random symmetric matric $Q \in S^{d\times d}$,we have$$P(\lambda_{max}(Q)\ge t)\le \inf_{\lambda \ge 0}[\frac{tr(\mathbb E(e^{\lambda Q}))}{e^{\lambda t}}]$$
so I just need to prove$$\lim_{N \to \infty} P(|\lambda_{max}(X)| \geq N^{1/2 + \delta}) = 0$$
Then by the condition of the problem and use the inequality and let $N \to \infty$,the conclusion has been proved.
If the thinking true?Any help is much appreciated!
The problem comes from S.-T. Yau College Student Mathematics Contests 2016 Probability and Statistics

Did you consider implementing the hint? We have $\operatorname{tr}|X|^2=N^2$, so your hint says $||X||_{\text{op.}}\leq N$. But this is to crude, we want something $\sim \sqrt{N}$.

@AntonSteinfadt.Thanks for your suggestions,sir.I had considered implementing the hint,too.But the question is that I could't know how to hold the bound when I use the form of squre.Maybe I should use the cauchy-schwarz inequality?The idea of why I use the matrix chernoff is the hint with respect to trade.
